# Too many short PHP files

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database

I searched a bit around before realizing I need some more info on this. I have an interactive website using ajax calls to get info from server. The (authenticated) user will click around quite a bit to manipulate this data, and it will be continously uploaded to server. The thing I'm not sure about is how to do this in the best possible manner, so that my project is scalable if necessary in the future.

To give an example. User logs in and a list view is filled up with data from server. If the user double clicks one of the elements in the list view, he can change the name, and the change should be uploaded to the server immediately. What I've done now is make a file called "changeName.php" which gets called. If the user clicks something else, let's say there are ten different buttons that each changes a particular setting. How would I go about uploading all of these different data changes without having ten different php-files all doing there own little thing? I hope I explained things well enough, but if something is confusing, I'll try my best at clarifying.

Comment: is it too many files, or, are the files just not organized in such a way that they can be easily found.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't an easy way to do what you'd like. I would suggest you look into PHP routers, as this will allow you to respond to differant types of requests.

Example would be you have a User.php file, that responds to POST, GET and PUT requests. The POST might create a new user, where GET could authenticate the user, and PUT might allow you to change usernames.

I would suggest you look into PHP routers.

Comment: No, there won't be that many files as it is a relatively small project by now, but I'm trying to find out if it's the right way to do it. If my web page has a lot of these "small transactions" with the server (say 20 per minute per user), is it normal to have a php file for each of these small functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than POST the changes to one PHP file, you can pass the request to a single php file that handles multiple operations. Include the type of request in the POST data itself. Then for instance that file can use a switch statement on that key to determine which operation to perform, and then call a particular function in the file to process the data.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['_action'] ) ) {
  switch ( $_POST['_action'] ) {
    'delete':
       deleteRow();
       break;
    'update':
       updateRow();
       break;
    'default':
       foo();
  }
}
// Functions omitted
```

Note that as others have said, using a proper MVC framework will make this much easier for you and will have other benefits (security, extensibility, etc). In particular, you can have a framework to take care of routing requests for you.

In a small or prototype project where you don't want to rely on a framework, using a method like the switch statement above can at least get you started.

Comment: I actually considered doing this. It might be a very good solution in my case. I think a framework might be a bit overkill, at least at this stage. Thanks for the code example!

Comment: You're welcome -- it definitely is useful to at least group related operations in the same file

Answer (score 0):

The best way to keep this organised is to use a proper framework. Laravel is a great option for this and will help keep your code well organised and maintainable.

Comment: I am very new to web development, so I haven't taken a look at PHP frameworks yet. Laravel looks very exciting, and I'll consider using it at a later stage as it is a bit overkill at this point. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @user2727241 It might actually be better to start with a framework as it will teach you mvc.

Comment: I'm used to mvc from coding in c++, and it is a great way to structure software.  I'll take a closer look at the framework.

Comment: @user2727241 it's the age-old debate, learn the tech or learn the thing that makes the tech easier? From the scope you've described, I think using a framework makes a lot of sense. Beyond very very simple apps, you'd be hard-pressed to find a developer who doesn't use a framework. The flip-side is that there are a lot of JS "developers" who only know jQuery, not JavaScript.